# Why does the author mention that tree frog calling is said to be “the most energetically expensive behavior yet measured in any vertebrate"?

Tags: exam-questions, reading-comprehension

Why does the author mention that tree frog calling is said to be “the most energetically expensive behavior yet measured in any vertebrate"?

A. explain why it is important for tree frogs to be in top physical condition

B. To distinguish tree frogs from other species of frogs

C. To indicate that survival is more difficult for frogs than for other vertebrates

D. To emphasize how physical effort calling requires

> Sound frequencies-or pitch-can also convey information about the calling male because the vocal apparatus grows larger as the frog grows older. In some frogs, the pitch of individual sounds varies with so that older and larger males give lower-pitched calls. Sound pitch is affected by temperature; small males can mimic the lower pitch of larger, older males by calling from colder locations. Finally, the length of time that an individual can afford to spend calling is a good indicator of his health. Many frogs invest considerable energy in calling, both because they do not feed and because it is a physically demanding behavior that relies on rapid muscular contractions of the vocalization apparatus. This effort can be debilitating in a male frog that is not in top physical condition. Calling in tree frogs is said to be the most energetically expensive behavior yet measured in any vertebrate.

**The answer is A but I don't know why, I chose D because I think it is talking about the difficulty of producing the sound.**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about the English language itself.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the sentence immediately prior to it says this:

> This effort can be debilitating in a male frog that is not in top physical condition.

I would have to say the answer, from your list given, is:

> A. explain why it is important for tree frogs to be in top physical condition

Really though, it could also be C or D. The only one that doesn't really fit is B because nothing in the paragraph compares it to other frogs, only other vertibrates, but it would depend on the wider context beyond this paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

B and C are simply not discussed in the quoted passage. In terms of test taking, you could exclude them on that basis alone.

More cogently, with respect to B, maintaining a blue whale's body temperature is undoubtedly more demanding of energy in absolute terms than anything a tree frog can do so what is being discussed is expenditure of energy relative to something. Therefore, the fact that the calling is very energy-intensive cannot distinguish among species. Frankly, if this question came from a test on comprehending English, my opinion is that way too much extraneous information is required to make it a reasonable question. If, however, it came from a test on biophysics, it is a perfectly reasonable question.

As for C, there is absolutely nothing in the passage to indicate that survival is harder for frogs than for salamanders. Calling may be energy-intensive, but presumably the expenditure is worth it in terms of survival. This question would be highly suitable for a test in evolutionary biology, but it is at least a stretch if it comes from a test on comprehending English.

As for D, it is true that the passage indicates that calling requires physical effort, but that does not explain why it is mentioned that, relatively, it requires maximum physical effort. The statement goes far beyond what anyone would need to deduce that some effort is required.

To sum up. If this came from a test on comprehending written English, I find it too dependent on extraneous knowledge to be fair. If it came from a test in some branch of biology, it seems eminently fair.